# How to adjust clover code coverage metric for jenkins?

Tags: hudson, code-coverage, jenkins, clover

This is the plugin I need some help for... http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clover+Plugin

I'd like to know how I need to adjust the Coverage Metric Targets the right way.

My code coverage is 35% methods, 0% conditionals, 60% statements. The metric is adjustet this way.

100% health: 10 / -1 / 10

0% health: 0 / -1 / 0

unstable: 0 / -1 / 0

Now I wonder why Jenkins still shows clouds because of Clover Coverage. How to set up these plug-in to get back the sun?

Thanks in advance!